# Unexpected error near token 'done'

Tags: bash

I wrote this script to automatically make copy of HAML file if it doesn't exist or if it's different than the older one and process two scripts but I get this error whenever I want to run it.

```
while true do;

    if [ ! -f index_copy.haml ]; then

        echo "\e[33mCreating 'index_copy.haml' file."
        cp index.haml index_copy.haml

        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "\e[36mDone."
        else
            echo "\e[32mError!"
        fi

    fi

    if cmp -s "index.haml" "index_copy.haml" ; then

        cp index.haml index_copy.haml
        echo -e "\e[34mProcessing HAML...\n"
        haml index.haml index.html 
        cd css
        echo -e "\e[32mProcessing SCSS...\n"
        sass style.scss style.css
        cd ..
        echo -e "\e[36mDone."

    fi

done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First line, replace :

```
while true do;
```

with :

```
while true; do
```